# Get dynamic hubtile name to create secondary tiles

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

When I was working with static hubtiles, I was creating the secondary tiles using a switch and cases, with every case to be the name of the hubtile.
This line of code was getting me the name of the clicked hubtile:

```
string clickedElement = ((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(sender)).Name;
```

and I could use it to create them.

I'm trying to make dynamic hubtiles now to be able to be pinned to start using the Hold event, but that line now gets " ".

My tiles (8) are created from an xml file

```
<root>
 <categories>
  <category>
   <categoryID>1</categoryID>
   <categoryName>chicken</categoryName>
   <ImageUri>chicken1.png</ImageUri>
  </category>
  ...
 </categories>
</root>
```

the code to read the xml file:

```
        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("xmlFiles/categories.xml");

        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("category")
                   select new Category
                   {
                       categoryID = (string)query.Element("categoryID"),
                       categoryName = (string)query.Element("categoryName"),
                   };
       tileList.ItemsSource = data;
```

xaml code is:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tileList">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:HubTile Margin="25" 
        Title="{Binding categoryName}" 
        Source="{Binding ImageUri}"
        Tap="Selection_Tap" 
        Hold="SelectionPin_Hold">
                    </toolkit:HubTile>
                </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And the code to create live tiles

```
private void CreateLiveTile(HubTile hubtile, string Name)
    {
        StandardTileData LiveTile = new StandardTileData
        {
            Title = hubtile.Title,
            BackBackgroundImage = (hubtile.Source as BitmapImage).UriSource
        };
        ShellTile Tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("Name=" + Name));
        {
            if (Tile == null)
            {
                ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Name=" + Name,UriKind.Relative), LiveTile);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Tile already pinned");
            }
        }
    }
```

CreateLive tiles method never actually worked correctly. It was pinning secondary tiles to the screen alright, but when those tiles where tapped, they were returning me to the MainPage.xaml rather than the navigation Uri the originals were going to. But don't bother with that, I changed my code so each hubtile goes to the same page but different data is shown dynamically from another xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found it. My misunderstanding. All I have to use now is

```
string clickedElement = ((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(sender)).Tag;
```